# Trying to install iTunes 7.2 to sync music with iPhone 4S

Tags: wine, iphone, itunes

I'm trying to install iTunes. I followed the instructions from the guy on YouTube to the letter. His first instruction was to download iTunes 7.2 which I in fact did, but when I try to install that file to my Ubuntu outright I keep getting the pop up  "The iTunes folder cannot be found or created".

I've worked on this watching multiple videos only to fail miserably, I have iPhone 4S but I do not have Windows OS installed on my PC in order to put music on my iPhone, I am only running Ubuntu  14.10 LTS at this very moment.

Comment: itunes will not run on Ubuntu. Reportedly it does not work very well under wine either.  The only solid solution I have found is to run a virtual windows machine.  Then it works fine.

Comment: maybe also [gtkpod](http://www.gtkpod.org/wiki/Home) is an option...

Answer (score 3):

Quote from [Top 5 iTunes Alternatives On Ubuntu 14.04](http://www.ubuntufree.com/top-5-itunes-alternatives-on-ubuntu-14-04/) on ubuntufree.com:

> **Is it possible to run iTunes on Ubuntu ?**
>
> No, you unfortunately can NOT run iTunes on Ubuntu or any other Linux
> distro. People will tell you there are weird ways to get iTunes
> running in Ubuntu, but I’ve never seen anyone successfully do it or
> give instructions that someone else could follow to successfully run
> iTunes in Ubuntu. Apple simply refuses to make a working iTunes
> version for Ubuntu at this time. So rather than spend energy looking
> for it, you'd better download music manager similiar to iTunes.
>
> **1. Rhythmbox**
>
> [image: Source: webupd8.com]
>
> Being the default music player on Ubuntu, Rhythmbox is considered to
> be the most stable, yet most powerful music player around. With a user
> interface similar to iTunes, this free application not only lets you
> listen to your favorite music but also lets you enjoy podcasts and
> radio as well. Furthermore, it lets you create playlists so that you
> won’t have to look for your favorite songs every single time.
>
> One of the biggest advantages that Rhythmbox has over other media
> players is it recognizes most of the popular devices like iPhone,
> iPod, and even the latest Android phones. This means that you can
> connect your device to your computer and transfer your favorite music
> to it directly from Rhythmbox. If you’re using the latest version of
> Ubuntu, Rhythmbox comes pre-installed.
>
> **2. Banshee**
>
> [image: Source: image.google.com]
>
> Banshee is another free media player that has an interface that is
> similar to iTunes. Like iTunes, it can play music, movies, and
> audiobooks as well. Once installed, all you have to do is add your
> media to its library and start search for your favorite tracks. If you
> want to buy new tracks, Banshee takes care of that too by integrating
> with Amazon’s online music store. Though not updated as often as
> Rhythmbox, Banshee remains one of the most popular players iTunes
> lovers flock to.
>
> **3. Amarok**
>
> [image: Source: Ubuntuguide.net]
>
> Unlike Rhythmbox or Banshee, doesn’t have an interface similar to
> iTunes(Which is not a bad thing!). Instead, it comes with a simple
> layout that makes discovering and playing your music easier. Once
> installed, you’ll be able to search, manage, and listen to your
> favorite music just like you used to on iTunes. The application comes
> with playing statistics, file tracking, dynamic playlists, and many
> other features that make it a really good alternative to Apple’s
> famous music player.
>
> [...]

Answer (score 0):

**Transferring music and access to files** on the device is implemented through [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) ([Wiki article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PortableDevices/iPhone)) in various applications on Ubuntu. You don't need iTunes for that.

Related: [Firmware update for iPod Touch (iPhone)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/182/40581)

---

> I'm trying to install iTunes. I followed the instructions from the guy on YouTube to the letter.

There are a lot of videos on YouTube, you need to be more specific than that.

> His first instruction was to download iTunes 7.2

This version was released in [2007](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_iTunes#iTunes_7)...

> I have iPhone 4S but I do not have Windows OS installed on my PC in order to put music on my iPhone

and the iPhone 4S was released in [2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_4S). In other words this version may not properly support all the functionality you would expect from iTunes working with your phone.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Pilot6 The link is an answer to the question and lists alternatives for the task "transferring music to an iDevice". I improved the wording a bit. Notice how the other answer was a non-obvious almost entirely quoted article from another site (probably beyond what copyright permits and relicensing not permitted at all). Also it should be mentioned that installing a legacy iTunes version is not recommended to get all functionality of iTunes (because unfortunately it is more than a media player) for newer devices or devices running an up to date version of iOS, which is what I did.